# Monitor MongoDB Atlas data transfer costs

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, billing

I have a MongoDB Atlas cluster that serves many customers. Each customer has its own database on the cluster.

I would like to reduce my application's impact on MongoDB data transfer costs, which have been increasing for the last few days, but the billing info provided by Atlas does not break down prices per database. Therefore, I have no way of knowing which customers are costly and what are the most costly queries in terms of data transfer.

Moreover, using the prices on a daily basis and a few queries, I cannot correlate insertion of resources in my application with prices. For example, let's say my resources are Cats, one day it will cost 5$ of data transfer with 5000 Cats inserted in total in the databases, but the next day, it's going to cost 13$ with 1500 Cats inserted.

Do you know of tools or something in the Atlas dashboard I might've missed that could help me better track costs per customer, or say, a cost per Cat (in my example) so that I build a pricing model for my customers?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely going to need separate projects and deployments.

A MongoDB client instance is generally capable of using any database on the server (subject to authorization rules and APIs provided in the language in question), therefore to get a breakdown of data transfer by database would require the server to track bytes transferred per operation and then aggregate those counts. As far as I know this isn't a feature that currently exists.

The most practical way of tracking this today is probably writing a layer on top of the driver on the client side that would look at data actually received.